# Loading-behaviour | Include vs Projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, projection, eager-loading

I have a question regarding a different loading behaviour when using EFCore 5 Code First.

First the model:

```cs
public class Store {
  ICollection<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
}

public class Customer{
  public Store Store {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ViewModel {
  ICollection<Customers> Customers {get;set;}
}
```

When using

```cs
DbContext.Stores.Include(store=>store.Customers)
    .ToList()
    .Select(store => new ViewModel{Customers = store.Customers})
```

and trying to parse it into a JSON I get an error caused by a looping reference (`Store.Customer.Store.Customer...` etc.)

But when I am using a Projection

```cs
DbContext.Stores
  .Select(store => new ViewModel{Customers = store.Customers})
  .ToList();
```

the result won't have any looping references.
I know that the projection will result into a lazy loading behaviour when accessing `Store.Customer` but does it restrict its loading to the navigation-property only (no backreference to `Store` created!)?
Also I never had the situation that eager loading also loads the navigation property of the included navigation-property by default.

Thanks for your time and answers!

Answer (score 0):

When you just load data via `Include`

```cs
DbContext.Stores.Include(store => store.Customers)
   .ToList()
```

EF tracks entities in ChangeTracker and fixup all references of already loaded objects. That's why you have error with `looping reference`. Try `AsNoTracking()`, which should avoid such error.

When you load objects via custom projection `Select`. EF do not track entities and ignores `Include`. So no `looping reference` error should happen.